# What is the ratio of uncountable nouns to countable nouns in the English language?

Tags: english, countability

I want to make the claim that uncountable nouns far outweigh countable ones in the English language, but a cursory search of the web did not lead me to anything that might support this claim, so all I have right now are my own personal observations.  As much as there is to be said for experiential learning, it lacks a certain authoritativeness usually required when trying to make a point about something.  Do any of you reading this happen to know if anyone has attempted to quantify such a thing?

Comment: Ngram Viewer shows that 'much' has actually declined relative to 'many' -- and just using your question as a sample, it has far more countable nouns.

Comment: Since most nouns can be used either as a count or a mass noun, it's hard to see how anybody could count either, let alone their ratio.

Comment: @jlawler  You make a good point, but, without thinking too long and hard about this, I do believe some nouns are _typically_ thought of as uncountable (e.g., water, rice, bread).  And, presumbably, one could filter out all instances of "of" + uncountable noun (because typically this is how these types of nouns appear to be made countable).  For example, _We have water._ vs. _We have several **bottles of** water._

Comment: @jlawler  But seeing as how the number of combinations that could be made rendering an uncountable noun into a countable one would be a mighty sum indeed, perhaps my query is too daunting for most to want to tackle.  However, I would think that someone who has studied English collocations for a decent amount of time would be able to at least make a stab at this.  Even so, I imagine it sounds a bit tedious and perhaps not much could be gained from it.  An excellent project for a linguistics grad student perhaps?